# change value of $request before validation in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5.5

I have a form in `route('users.create')`.

I send form data to this function in its contoller:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{

    return redirect(route('users.create'));
}
```

for validation I create a class in

**App\Http\Requests\Panel\Users\UserRequest;**

```
class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        if($this->method() == 'POST') {
             return [
                 'first_name' => 'required|max:250',
```

It works.

But How can I change `first_name` value before validation (and before save in DB)?

(Also with failed validation, I want to see new data in `old('first_name')`

**Update**

I try this:

```
 public function rules()
    {
     $input = $this->all();


     $input['first_name'] = 'Mr '.$request->first_name;
     $this->replace($input);

     if($this->method() == 'POST') {
```

It works before `if($this->method() == 'POST') {` But It has not effect for validation or for `old()` function

Answer (score 31):

Override the `prepareForValidation()` method of the `FormRequest`.

So in `App\Http\Requests\Panel\Users\UserRequest`:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    if ($this->has('first_name'))
        $this->merge(['first_name'=>'Mr '.$this->first_name]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
$request->merge(['New Key' => 'New Value']);
```

In your case it can be as follows for saving

```
$this->merge(['first_name'=>'Mr '.$this->first_name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing the validation in the controller? Than you can change things before you validate it and doing your db stuff afterward.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->first_name = 'Mr '.$request->first_name;

    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:250',
    ])->validate();

    // ToDo save to DB

    return redirect(route('users.create'));
}
```

See also https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

Comment: Is it not possible to do it on my method? Please see my update.